# Server 2012 R2 Domain Controller in 2003 Functional Level Forest

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

My Forest Functional Level is 2003.  I am adding a new Domain Infrastructure.  Can I use 2012 R2 for the new DCs? Or do I need to go for Server 2008 R2?

What are the Server version and Domain/Forest Functional Level compatibility restrictions?

Comment: What?  Seriously, what are you asking?

Comment: @HopelessN00b I think he's asking whether he can install domain controllers that run a Server 2012 R2 OS into a domain with a 2003 forest functional level as well as existing domain controllers that run Server 2003. And what he'll be missing out on by staying at a forest and domain functional level of 2003 as opposed to upgrading FFL/DFL to 2012 R2.

Answer (score 6):

If you had out the tiniest amount of effort into research before asking, you would have found that the answer is **yes**. You can promote 2012 R2 Domain Controllers into a 2003 DFL domain.